# Django: Matching anything but forward slash in url?

Tags: python, django

The problem I have is this:

```
url(r'^books/(.*?)/$', views.list_books),
url(r'^books/(.*?)/availability/$', views.book_availability),
```

I've always used `(.*?)` to match anything, but in this case it doesn't work since it matches the first pattern no matter what. Basically I want to have this working: `books/A56/availability`, but `A56/availability` matches `books/(.*?)/$` and not `books/(.*?)/availability/$` like it's supposed to.

How would I match this? I guess what I want is "match anything until a forward dash" or something similar.

Comment: What You have in template.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request):

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first one that matches the requested URL.

So you should put the second pattern before the first or [name your `url` patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^books/(.*?)/availability/$', views.book_availability),
    url(r'^books/(.*?)/$', views.list_books),
]
```